# What's the most simple way to get the value of a single column from a single row table in SQLite using C# sqlite-net-pcl library

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

In SQLite is there a better way to get the value of the one and only version column in the Schema table:

```
db2.CreateTable<Schema>();
db2.Insert(new Schema() { SchemaGuid = new Guid().ToString(), Version = 1 });
public class Schema
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string SchemaGuid   { get; set; }
    public int    Version      { get; set; }
}

var version = RunQuery<Schema>($"SELECT * FROM Schema").FirstOrDefault().Version;
```

Also if I want to update to version = 2.  How can I do that with SQLite's sqlite-net-pcl library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is any simpler than what you're already doing

```
var version = RunQuery<int>($"SELECT Version FROM Schema").FirstOrDefault();
```